# How to create this kind of rig system? When Ctrl bone bend column of DEF bones

Tags: rigging

The Ctrl bone should bend the column of the DEF bones.

Are there any ready-made solutions on how to make such a rig?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK - no - you have to rig it manually - maybe you wanna change your question to...how can i rig...?

Answer (score 2):

Since your prerequisite isn't exact, i assumed that only the upper and lower bones should bend, not the middle ones. Because your middle bones have all equal length in your sketch.

So create 5 bones likes this:

[image]

Bone.R2 has a stretch to constraint to Bone.R1:

[image]

Bone.R1 has a copy location of Controller like this:

[image]

Controller is locked like this, so it just moves on y

[image]

No bone has any parent.

The lower bones have the same constraints as the upper bones, just with different targets.

result:

[image]